# How to compare strings in python that also contains other ascii symbols like underscores?

Tags: python, compare, ascii, string-comparison, alphabetical

I have a list of strings, make it two for this example:

`list = ["ACTVN_Cars", "ACT_CFR_AD"]`

Then i try to check if the list is sorted alphabetically with this code:

`test.verify(list[0].lower() <= list[1].lower())`

And with that i run into an error. Why does the test work other strings, but not for this one?
And what would be a good way to test the list?

Comment: Your list is invalid, unless those are variables? `list = ["ACTVN_Cars", "ACT_CFR_AD"]`

Comment: My fault, corrected it. Thank you for the hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't seem to reproduce, can you share your test.verify() code:

```
list = ["ATVN_Cars", "ACT_CFR_AD"]
list[0] < list[1]
>>> False
list[0] > list[1]
>>> True
list[0].lower() > list[1].lower()
>>> True
```

Answering your other question the easiest way to "test" something is with `assert`

```
assert list[0] > list[1] is True
```

Regarding the _ character:

```
ord("_")
>>> 95
ord("a")
>>> 97
ord("A")
>>> 65

So: 
"A" < "_" < "a"
>> True
```

Comment: I think i should not have said error. The test just Fails. 
The codeline is like the line above. 

test.verfiy() Comes from a Framework called squish which is used for GUI Tests. 

Or do i thought about it wrong?

In my opinion "ACTVN_Cars" should come, alphabetical wise, before "ACT_CFR_AD"

Answer (score 0):

list = ["ACTVN_Cars", "ACT_CFR_AD"]

if list[0]< list[1]:

```
print(list[1])
```

elif list[0]>list[1]:

```
print(list[0])
```

else:
    print("Strings are equal")